# Tracking screen recorder in windows app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I am working on a web project where content security is client's first priority. I need to create a windows app which will track if the user while visiting the website, is running any screen recorder. If he is, I need to log him out. I have knowledge on c#, vb.net. Can you please tell me if it is possible to track if screen recorder is running on user's computer?

Comment: What if the user is using camera to record ? :)

Comment: No, it's not possible. Any screen recorder application that *wanted* to hide itself from your detector would easily be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You seriously want to prevent access to a *web-site* being recorded?

The simple answer is no, you can't tell. However, MS does offer some content protection APIs that might be more what you need, *IF* you are rendering to a DirectX 11 surface:

[Direct 3D Video APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756736%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN has more info.

Answer (score 0):

It might cost colossal resources to implement such solution (that will have holes and must be maintained). Monitoring web site by means of a desktop app sounds like a dirty insecure hack. What if the user has a mobile phone with the camera?

Better, you shall rely upon standard widely accepted security principles of HTTP/TSL, such as proper authentication, authorisation, security policies, encryption, strong passwords etc.