# Detecting screen recording in windows using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, screen-recording

I am trying to write an application in C# where I can detect if another application is capturing a video of the screen in Windows. I can look at process list and detect if a particular process is running but it is not efficient as process name of the capturing application can be changed. Can any one please tell me if there is any way to do this ? Thanks !

Comment: Some of the answers on this post might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083261/tracking-screen-recorder-in-windows-app?rq=1

Comment: No - what if it is remote desktop or some other sort of visualized video card? The only thing that may be close to preventing unauthorized recording is [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDCP).

Comment: @ravuya , thanks for the response ,  I tried to check that thread, but nothing concrete is mentioned there

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov , thank you for responding, HDCP is proprietary so using that may not be possible...

Answer (score 4):

If all you're trying to do is detect whether a process on the same computer is recording the screen you can probably find a way to do it for some stuff.  There are certain APIs that are used by a lot of screen recording software that you can intercept with EasyHook or something similar, but you'll miss the rest of them that work differently.

UltraVNC for instance has a Mirror Video Driver that you can install that gives you notifications of screen updates as well as direct access to the video framebuffer, which is great for screen recording or recasting.  How will your code react to that?

The bigger problem is that simply scanning the local machine is insufficient to protect your application from being recorded.  You can make it more difficult by mixing in various techniques like hardware overlay and HDCP for your output.

The biggest problem of course is that there is no way to stop someone from pointing a camera at their monitor.

What you will end up with is a lot of time spent on the development with a net result of not much added security... and a little more inconvenience to your end users.  And someone determined to defeat it only needs to do a little code patch to your application or point a cell-phone camera in the right direction and it's bye-bye security.

Seems silly to me.

Comment: thanks for the response , is there any documentation on using these APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Process name can be changed; but you cannot change "main window title".
You can consider well known screen capture programs main window title at runtime.